# Why are these error messages inconsistent when using NSE in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, error-handling, tidyeval, nse

## Question

Why do I get inconsistent error messages in R from a function that uses non-standard evaluation, and what is the best way to control this / write the function?

### Initial setup that works as intended:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(a = c(1,4,9),
             b = c("a", "b", "c"))
> df
# A tibble: 3 × 2
      a b    
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1 a    
2     4 b    
3     9 c    

myFun1 <- function(df, y){
  df <- df %>%
    mutate(c = str_to_upper({{y}}))
  return(df)
}

> myFun1(df, y = b)
# A tibble: 3 × 3
      a b     c    
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1     1 a     A    
2     4 b     B    
3     9 c     C
```

Everything above works as intended.  There are no errors with my function calls as shown.

### Problem starts here

I made a mistake by not passing the dataframe's column as a parameter in the call, but received no error message:

```
> myFun1(df)     # Note the missing parameter of 'y = b' on this function call.
# A tibble: 3 × 3
      a b     c    
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1     1 a     ""   
2     4 b     ""   
3     9 c     ""
```

My expectation when calling a function with missing parameters is that it would throw an error, which does not happen. (Side question: Why does it return an empty string "" for column c?)

I thought I could helpfully write my own error message -- which worked -- but not in the way I intended:

```
myFun2 <- function(df, y){
  if(is.null(y)){            
    stop("You are missing 'y'")
  }
  df <- df %>%
    mutate(c = str_to_upper({{y}}))
  return(df)
}

> myFun2(df)
Error in myFun2(df) : argument "y" is missing, with no default
```

That error above is triggered by `is.null(y)` and not by my `if(){stop()}` (so you **ARE NOT** seeing my intended error message), but what is interesting to me is that **THIS IS THE ERROR MESSAGE I WAS HOPING/EXPECTING TO SEE** when I called `myFun1(df)`.  So it seems that my use of `{{y}}` in the function prevents the triggering of the error message.(?)

> Note: I realize (later, with more reading) that I could get my `stop()` message to trigger if I used `if(missing(y))`, but I'm more curious about the case above, where I get the error message I was originally hoping to get without the `if(){stop()}` call.

#### What if I try a different function, like `sum()`?

I tried to change functions, as below (shown working properly first):

```
myFun3 <- function(data, x){
  df <- data %>%
    mutate(c = sum({{x}}))
  return(df)
}

> myFun3(df, x = a)
# A tibble: 3 × 3
      a b         c
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
1     1 a        14
2     4 b        14
3     9 c        14
```

...and now with same mistake as before:

```
> myFun3(df)
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `c = sum()`.
Caused by error in `sum()`:
! invalid 'type' (symbol) of argument
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
Called from: signal_abort(cnd, .file)
Browse[1]>
```

So now I get an error message on the `sum()` call because the wrong type -- **(symbol)** -- is detected, which is my `{{x}}`.  Okay, that makes sense (I think), but why then do I not get that same error message on the call `str_to_upper({{y}})` ?  Isn't `{{y}}` also a symbol in my original bad call of `myFun1(df)`?  I am trying to understand this all in the context of learning non-standard evaluation, and I am reading [Advanced R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/), but this issue above seems pretty specific.  I appreciate any insight.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that `is.null` has to *evaluate* its argument to find out if the *value* of that argument is `NULL`. An object having a `NULL` value is not the same thing as that object not existing at all.

For example, I don't have an object called `bananas` in my global environment, so I expect to get an error if I do:

```r
bananas
#> Error: object 'bananas' not found
```

Of course, the same is true if I try to look up the value of bananas to find out if it is numeric:

```
is.numeric(bananas)
#> Error: object 'bananas' not found
```

Or if its value is `NA`:

```r
is.na(bananas)
#> Error: object 'bananas' not found
```

Or if its value is `NULL`:

```
is.null(bananas)
#> Error: object 'bananas' not found
```

Whereas, if we assign the name `bananas`, even as `NULL`, there is no such error, because now at least there is an object called `bananas`, albeit one with a `NULL` value.

```r
bananas <- NULL
bananas
#> NULL
is.null(bananas)
#> [1] TRUE
```

As you have discovered yourself, the correct usage would be to check `missing(y)`:

```r
myFun2 <- function(df, y) {
  if(missing(y)) stop("Argument y is missing")
  mutate(df, c = str_to_upper({{y}}))
}

myFun2(df)
#> Error in myFun2(df) : Argument y is missing
```

As for why `str_to_upper({{y}})` doesn't throw an error when `y` is missing yet `sum({{y}})` *does* throw an error is because of how the curly-curly operator works. Ultimately, a missing `y` value here will be converted to an empty symbol (the same type of object you get with `alist(a=)$a`). A symbol can be converted into a character (in this case the character `""`), so `as.character`, or any of the many functions that convert to character, will quite happily return an empty string here. Existence functions such as `is.numeric` or `is.na` will also work just fine, but they are testing a symbol.

On the other hand, if you try to do any math with the missing variable, you are trying to perform arithmetic on a symbol, which doesn't make sense and throws an error.

As for *why* the curly-curly operator allows a valid quosure even when its argument is missing, I can't say for sure whether this is an unavoidable side effect of the mechanism or a conscious design decision, but your plan to handle the case of a missing argument yourself is definitely a good idea either way.

Comment: This is great and answers all my questions.  I particularly appreciate the validation that using `missing()` as a check is good idea and I'm on the right track with that.  Thank you for the thorough answer.